# Android How to size and save camera picture as bitmap for display in fixed rect area within activity

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an app that takes pictures of items, and these items must be viewable in a certain fixed region on the ActivityScreen. The problem is the picture displayed in the activity from the saved bitmap, looks nothing like what I previewed and photographed.  It looks zoomed in and shows areas I did not even see in the preview when I took the picture:  Here is the key code lines

**IMAGE CAPTURE**:

```
surfHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

captImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.CamImageView);

byte [] photoData;
Camera cam;
SurfaceHolder surfHolder;
SurfaceView surfView;


Camera.PictureCallback cback;

cback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                        final int length = data.length;
                opts.inSampleSize = 4;
            final BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();    
            Bitmap bMap = null;

            try {

                    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, length, opts);

            } catch(Exception e) {

            }catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {

            } 

            captImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            if(bMap==null) {
               cam.startPreview();
            } else {
                             savePhotoButton.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                 takePhotoButton.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                 photoData = data;
            }
        }
 }
```

**IMAGE SAVE**:

```
captImageView.setImageBitmap(null);
// SAVE THE PICTURE   THIS SAVES PICTURE IN WRONG SIZE.  LOOKS LIKED ZOOMED IN NOT WHAT WAS PREVIEWED!!!


           public void photoSave(byte[] data) {

               final int length = data.length;
           final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;

                try {
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, length, options);
         int quality = 75;
             File file = new File(getDir(), fname);
         fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
         bMap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, fileOutputStream);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        }  catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {} }
```

IMAGE DISPLAY as DRAWABLE in ACTIVITY 
DOES NOT WORK SHOWS IMAGE AS ZOOMED OR PORTIONS NOT SEEN IN PREVIEW AT ALL WHEN PICTURE WAS TAKEN!!

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = inSampSize;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

Drawable drawable = bitmap;
ImageView pictureView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pictureViewer);
pictureView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: I am wondering if the problem is I need to use the height/width only that is supported by the Camera?  Could this be the problem?  Thanks