# Android Photo Size and Resolution

Tags: android, camera

Pardon the basic question, but I don't quite get how to work with Android Camera class and Parameters.

What I am trying to use Android API to take a picture that will display in a fixed area of my activity.  Its about 3inches by 2inches on screen.

Lets say I know that I want a picture that displays in a 360x220px area? I am talking about on the activity size. So I how do I match this up to the accepted picture size of the camera.  I mean I see it supports 480x800 and 800x480. This seems to actually be the closest size but its hard to find one thats really matches the display area I have?

So I don't know where to specify that size of picture to take that will look good in that area. Do I specify this during preview?  I mean I guess what I thought  I could do is preview in same size somehow as the display area I wanted to finally show the picture in?  Also how to save it off properly.  Should I just pick closest, save and then try to scale?  Are there any libraries I should be using for this beside Android SDK?

Sorry about rant. I just have a specific size(I can change it somewhat but I have to fix it and I don't think its 480x800) and I just want to take a picture that will fit in that area, save it load and display it there?  How do I do this?  I would like a preview that does not take up a bigger area, and a picture that looks just like what is previewed.

Whats happening now is pictures displaying that looked zoomed etc or two small, too big everything but what I want to display.

Comment: when I save and redisplay it actually shows areas I did not even see during preview??

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're doing- can you post the code that isn't working right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863253/android-how-to-size-and-save-camera-picture-as-bitmap-for-display-in-fixed-rect-a

Comment: I posted it above.  I will edit question so make it more clear